# Tf-Idf Vectorizer with LSTM in Keras Error: Expected LSTM to have 3 dimensions

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm working on a text classification problem which has ~1M reviews, based on which I have to predict the sentiment. However this  is a glimpse of my dataset:

```
In [3]:df=pd.read_csv('amazon_review.csv')
       df.head()
Out [3]:    
Review_no   reviewText                                    Sentiment
    1   I enjoy vintage books and movies so I enjoyed ...   Happy
    2   This book is a reissue of an old one; the auth...   Happy
    3   This was a fairly interesting read. It had ol...    Happy
    4   I'd never read any of the Amy Brewster mysteri...   Happy
    5   If you like period pieces - clothing, lingo, y...   Happy
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
In [10]: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
         test_size=0.33)
In[11]: y_train = y_train.map({"Happy": 1, "Content" : 2, "Unhappy" : 3 })
         y_test = y_test.map({"Happy": 1, "Content" : 2, "Unhappy" : 3 })
In [12]: y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
         y_test=to_categorical(y_test)
In [13]: all_text=X_train.append(X_test)
In [14]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

         word_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
           sublinear_tf=True,
           strip_accents='unicode',
           analyzer='word',
           token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
           stop_words='english',
           ngram_range=(1, 1),
           max_features=20000)
         word_vectorizer.fit(all_text)
         train_word_features = word_vectorizer.transform(X_train)
         test_word_features = word_vectorizer.transform(X_test)
In [15]: train_word_features.shape
Out [15]: (658118,20000)
In [16]: model = Sequential()
         model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,input_shape= 
         (658118,20000)))
         model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
In [17]: model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
In [18]: model.fit(train_word_features, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=15,
          validation_data=(test_word_features, y_test))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-46b758e790c5> in <module>()
      2           batch_size=batch_size,
      3           epochs=15,
----> 4           validation_data=(test_word_features, y_test))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    958                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    959                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 960                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    961 
    962     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1572             class_weight=class_weight,
   1573             check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1574             batch_size=batch_size)
   1575         # Prepare validation data.
   1576         do_validation = False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)
   1405                                     self._feed_input_shapes,
   1406                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1407                                     exception_prefix='input')
   1408         y = _standardize_input_data(y, self._feed_output_names,
   1409                                     output_shapes,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    139                                  ' to have ' + str(len(shapes[i])) +
    140                                  ' dimensions, but got array with shape ' +
--> 141                                  str(array.shape))
    142             for j, (dim, ref_dim) in enumerate(zip(array.shape, shapes[i])):
    143                 if not j and not check_batch_axis:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_14_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (658118, 20000)
```

So I'm not able to understand where is the problem going. How do I change the dimension?
`.to_array` causes a memory error because its a huge dataset.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation TfidfVectorizer gives you a sparse matrix:

> Returns:
>   X : sparse matrix, [n_samples, n_features]
>       Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.

LSTM are used for sequences, so your data has to be in the form of sequences. Your data is a sparse matrix. Anyway I think you should also take a look into word embeddings, because it makes no sense to use the output of TfidfVectorizer in LSTMs. If you want to use TFIDF, take a look at bag of word models.

Maybe take a look at some blog about sentiment analysis, there are millions about it. [example](https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/sentiment-detection-with-keras-word-embeddings-and-lstm-deep-learning-networks)

Comment: Actually I want to do an experimentation with different word vectorizer method and see which gives the highest accuracy. So what are the different methods except word2vec and GloVe embedding?

Comment: I would start with something like this example. [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py)